# Restangular setBaseUrl in the run messed up?

Tags: api, url, angularjs, service, restangular

I have three service in my angular service module, and I put

```
Restangular.setBaseUrl(api_url);
```

in each of my service with different api_url, and I expect to use different service with different url;

but when I post to one of the service say api_url = a/v1/c/, what I get is post to api_url = b/v1/c;

I think the problem is the setBaseUrl part, for example:

```
factory.Aservice = function(Restangular){
    Restangular.setBaseUrl('/a/v1');

    var alist= Restangular.all('c/');

    return {
        createA:function(){
            alist.post(data)
        }
    }
}

 factory.Bservice = function(Restangular){
    Restangular.setBaseUrl('/b/v1');

    var blist= Restangular.all('d/');

    return {
        createB:function(){
            blist.post(data)
        }
    }
}
```

when I call Aservice.createA(),the post url is '/b/v1/c',which is wrong.

any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to understand scoping of a serivce. Angular instantiates services in a lazily-loaded manner. Since both your services operate on the same Restangular, it is normal that whichever service loaded last, would be the one that will override the restangular configuration last:

http://plnkr.co/edit/o974TqeunG9DGQONRNDT?p=preview

I created a Plunkr which illustrates that.

Also created a Plunkr which shows the correct way to do that.

http://plnkr.co/edit/XYEQpLZaRAjxNUImCJMP?p=preview

Comment: oh,that's confusing. so I should inject the service in order?

Comment: No, you should never rely on order of injecting. You should make sure that each service call goes through the appropriate Restangular configuration, as shown in the second plunkr.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use separate configurations for each service as explained here: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-to-create-a-restangular-service-with-a-different-configuration-from-the-global-one

```
app.factory('ServiceA', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    // service has different address from serviceB
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://service-a.example.com/a/v1');
  });
});

app.factory('ServiceB', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    // service has different address from serviceA
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://service-b.example.com/b/v1');
  });
});
```